# Setting timeout for JDBC for Driver.connect()

Tags: jdbc, connection, timeout

Is there a way to set the timeout value in JDBC for the duration it tries to create a connection?(i.e. timeout for `Driver.connect()` )

Comment: You shouldn't use `Driver.connect()` directly, but connect through `DriverManager` (or a `DataSource`) instead.

Comment: Using a driver implementation directly binds you to a specific driver implementation instead of only the API in the `java.sql` package; this makes it easier to swap drivers. `DriverManager` is the standard API to connect to a database. It will even load all available drivers from the classpath (assuming JDBC 4 compliant drivers).

Comment: I believe you but that's a bit too complicated for me.

Comment: The only difference in code is between `yourDriver.connect(url, properties)` and `DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties)` (or one of the other overloads)...

Comment: I see but maybe the reason why we are using Driver is that we have our own getConnection method. I am not exactly capable of knowing the whole code of our project. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#setLoginTimeout%28int%29). Just be aware that not all drivers support this. Some drivers (also) provide a connection property to set the connect timeout.

Note that some JDBC drivers also have a connection timeout, which is not the same as the connect/login timeout. The connection timeout is - usually - the blocking timeout of the socket.